# Non-abelian $p$-group; abelian subgroups of index $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I'm trying to prove the following problem:

> (a) Let $G$ be a non-abelian $p$-group with an abelian subgroup of index $p$. Then the number of abelian subgroups of $G$ of index $p$ is either $1$ or $p+1$; in the latter case the center of $G$ has index $p^2$.
>
> (b) A nilpotent group of class $3$ and order $16$ has exactly one cyclic subgroup of index $2$.

I've made some progress towards (a) and tried to use (a) to show (b). But despite thinking about this for a few days I'm missing something and I can't quite finish off my argument. Here is an outline of the main results that I have managed to show; essentially, I think I've shown that for part (a), if there is more than one than there must be at least $p+1$.

Assume that there is more than one abelian subgroup of index $p$. Let $H$ and $K$ be two of them. Then they are both maximal and hence normal in $G$, and then $G=HK$. Then I was able to show that $H \cap K \leq Z(G)$, and then it follows that $Z(G)$ has index $p^2$ (as $G$ is non-abelian).

So now I want to show that there are exactly $p+1$ abelian subgroups of index $p$. Suppose $L$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $p$ containing $H \cap K$. Then $L \lhd G$. Since $H \cap K \lhd G$ and it has index $p^2$, then $L/(H \cap K)$ is cyclic of order $p$. From this I was able to show that $L$ is abelian.

Now consider $G/(H \cap K)$, which has order $p^2$; however it can't be cyclic since it has two subgroups of order $p$, namely $H/(H \cap K)$ and $K/(H \cap K)$. So $G/(H \cap K) \cong C_p \times C_p$, and it follows that it has $p+1$ subgroups of order $p$. This gives $p+1$ subgroups of $G$ of index $p$. By the above, each of these is abelian.

Now I need to show that there can't be more than $p+1$ such subgroups... but I'm a bit stuck here.

As for part (b), I thought I might be able to use (a) for this, if I can show that there does exist an abelian group of order 8 and it's cyclic. Somehow I need to use the fact that the group is of class 3. I try looking at the upper and lower central series but can't see a way of applying them. I would be grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in fact any abelian subgroup of index $p$ must contain the center: for if $H$ is maximal and abelian, and $Z(G)$ is not contained in $H$, then $G=HZ(G)$, which would make $G$ abelian. Therefore, if $H$ and $K$ are both abelian of index $p$, then $Z(G)\subseteq H\cap K$. If you have proven that $H\cap K\subseteq Z(G)$, then in fact we have that $H\cap K=Z(G)$ for any two distinct abelian subgroups of index $p$.

(And indeed: if $H\neq K$ are both abelian of index $p$, then for every $g\in G$ there exists $h\in H$, $k\in K$ with $g=hk$; given $x\in H\cap K$ we have $gx = (hk)x = x(hk) = xg$, since $x$ commutes with everything in $K$ and with everything in $H$, so $H\cap K\subseteq Z(G)$).

Conversely, if $M$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $Z(G)$ and is of index $p$, then it must be abelian (since $M/Z(G)$ is of order $p$). Thus, every abelian subgroup of $G$ of index $p$ corresponds to a subgroup of $G/Z(G)$, and you are done.

For part (b), show that (a) implies that if $G$ has more than one abelian subgroup of index $p$, then $G$ is of class exactly $2$: by the argument in (a), you know that $Z(G)$ has index $p^2$ in $G$, but that means that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, which means that $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$.

So if $G$ is of class $3$ and order $16$, then it has *at most* one abelian subgroup of order $8$. The center must be of order $2$: if the center were of order $4$, then $G/Z(G)$ would be of order $4$, hence abelian, so again we have that $G$ would be of class $2$. Thus, $G/Z(G)$ is of order $8$, and cannot be abelian. Therefore, $G/Z(G)$ is one of the two nonabelian groups of order $8$. If $G/Z(G)$ were quaternion, then it would have four cyclic subgroups of order $4$: each of them pull back to a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $8$, containing the center; and it is not hard to show that they are all abelian, contradicting the fact that $G$ has at most one abelian subgroup of order $8$. So $G/Z(G)$ must be dihedral. Verify that you get a cyclic subgroup of order $8$ in $G$ in this case.

**Added.** So, let us suppose that $G$ is of class $3$ and order $16$, and has a unique abelian subgroup of index $2$. We know $Z(G)$ is of order $2$, and that $G/Z(G)$ is dihedral of order $8$. Let $z\in G$ generate $Z(G)$, and let $x\in G$ map to a generator of the cyclic group of order $4$ in $G/Z(G)$. We know that $x$ has order either $4$ or $8$ in $G$. We aim to show that it has order $8$.

If $x$ has order $8$, we are done. Otherwise, $|x|=4$. Let $y\in G$ be such that $y$ maps to the generators of $G/Z(G)$ of order $2$, so that $yx = x^3y$ or $yx=x^3yz$. In the former case, we have $yx^2 = x^6y = x^2y$, so $x^2$ commutes with $x$, $y$, and $z$; in the latter case we would have $yx^2 = x^3yxz = x^6yz^2 = x^2y$, so again $x^2$ commutes with $x$, $y$, and $z$. Since $x$, $y$, and $z$ generate $G$, it follows that $x^2\in Z(G)$. But then the image of $x$ in $G/Z(G)$ would have order $2$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $x$ cannot have order $4$, and so must have order $8$, as desired.

Comment: I thought a bit about part (b): If we take $H≤ \frac{G}{Z(G)}=\mathbb Z_p×\mathbb Z_p$ with index $p$ then certainly $|H|=p$. It means that we have an element of order $p$ in this subgroup generating. Moreover, all elements in $=\mathbb Z_p×\mathbb Z_p$ take $p$ as their orders and so the number of all subgroups of order $p$ in $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$  is $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}$.

Comment: @Babak: No: if $G/Z(G)$ were isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, then $G$ would be of class $2$. But we are assuming that $G$ is of class $3$, so this cannot occur. That means that $Z(G)$ must be of order $2$, not $4$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get everything apart from the very last bit: showing that there *is* a cyclic subgroup of order $8$. I think of exhibiting an element of order $8$. I try letting $H/Z(G) \leq G/Z(G)$ be the cyclic group of order $4$ inside $D_8$. But in the pullback $H$ I was only able to show that there is an element with order divisible by $4$; so $H$ is either $C_8$ or $C_4 \times C_2$. What am I missing?

Comment: @under: I've added a proof that a pullback of the element of order $4$ in $D_8$ must have order $8$ in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for that. There is just one concept I'm still not entirely clear about: "In the latter case, we can replace $y$ with $yz$ so that we may assume that $yx=x^3y$". I get that $y$ and $yz$ both map to the same image, and once we replaced $y$ with $yz$ then we end up in the first case. But why can we do the replacement? The answer might be simple, but I'm not really clear on it, so would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: @under: We're just looking for appropriate elements that generate the group and have certain images in the quotient. But actually what I wrote is wrong: if $yx=x^3yz$, then $(yz)x = (yx)z = (x^3yz)z = x^3y$, not $x^3yz$. We need to do the same argument for that one. I'll fix it.

Comment: Yes I get the idea now, and it all makes sense, thanks for fixing that up.